# Use Groupby to construct a dataframe with value counts of other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two column features: startneighborhood and hour

`hour` can take any value from 1-24, i.e., `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]`

`startneighborhood` can be 37 different neighborhood options.

I want to find the number of hours for every neighborhood and use "hour" as an index.

So my matrix would be 24 rows x 37 columns, with the 1:24 hours array as my index and the 37 neighborhood as the column names.

How can I use Pandas to perform this computation? I'm a bit lost on the fastest way.

I've constructed the dataframe, with the index and the neighborhood names as the column names. I now just need to add the values..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im a little bit confused by the question but I think what you want to do is a crosstab

```
import pandas as pd
df = <...> #construct your dataframe
table = pd.crosstab(index=df.hour,columns=df.startneighborhood)
```

This will give you a 24x37 table where each element is the count of the number of occurrences of that combination of hour and startneighborhood.

Comment: Getting this error: TypeError: crosstab() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'

Comment: That is strange. Which version of Pandas are you running? Here is a link to the docs for crosstab in 0.14.1 http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html